# characters of each row of csv file to be passed to an argument in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a csv file with 1 column and 150 rows. I want to pass the content of the csv file to a shell script argument like
    `a=(1 2 3)`

I have used the code `a="$(<files.csv)"`,

but it takes all the characters in the csv file as one character, but not characters of each row as different character of "a". Please let me know how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `a=(1 2 3)` creates an array in bash (in some other shells it's just a syntax error), I assume you are trying to create an array.  If that is the case, try:

```
a=($(cat files.csv))
```

That is, just replace your double quotes with surrounding parentheses.